# Clearance gem queries for users too many times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, clearance

I am using clearance gem for authentication purpose and it is working very much fine. But, the problem with it I found is, it slows down the application. By taking a closer look at this, I found that it fetches user for each and every assets(JavaScripts, CSS and images) requested for the page.

Can anyone suggest me what can be the work around for this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This was [fixed in Clearance 1.0.0](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/commit/9d2f94955b18f9c2d382939245e027972c2aacb0)